# Let $f$ be continuous such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)/x<1$ Prove that there exists $c$ satisfying $f(c)=c$

Tags: limits, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous and nonenegative function on $I=[0,\infty)$ such that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}<1$$
Prove that $\exists c\ge 0$ s.t. $f(c)=c$

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$, note that $g$ is continuous on $I$ and $g(0)\ge 0$. Now we need $b$ such that $g(b)\le 0$ to apply the intermediate value theorem.

Let $$\ell =\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}<1$$
This means $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N>0$ such that $$x>N \implies \left| \frac{f(x)}
{x}-\ell \right|<\epsilon$$
Thus
$$x\ell -x(\epsilon +1)<g(x)<x\epsilon +x(\ell -1)$$

Here we have two methods. The first one is from my teacher which says, set $\epsilon =1-\ell $, $$2x(\ell-1)<g(x)<0\quad \forall x>N$$
Now just take $b=N+1$ and we're done by the intermediate value theorem. But here's my method ,

Assume $\forall x>0\quad g(x)>0$. Therefore $0<g(x)<x\epsilon +x(\ell -1)$ meaning $$1<\frac{f(x)}{x}<\epsilon +\ell \quad \forall x>N$$

Hence $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}\ge 1 $$

Contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. it is right.

Answer (score 3):

You could also note that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}-1<0$$ and use $g(0)\geq0$ to complete the IVT argument. (NOTE: We separated the limits only because of prior information that the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists).